# Deploy signatures to non-Exchange Outlook clients

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010, microsoft-outlook-2007, email-signature

In my office, I have a few computers that are running Outlook (some 2007, some 2010). They are **standalone** clients using IMAP; **there is no Exchange or AD present.**

**Is there any means in which I can deploy standardized email signatures to the Outlook clients?**

All of the research I've done all involve doing it with an Exchange server or Active Directory, but I can't afford nor want one.

Comment: http://www.immense.net/deploying-unified-email-signature-template-outlook/

Comment: http://www.symprex.com/products/email-signature-disclaimer-manager/

Comment: @techie007 Both of those require an AD.

Comment: I'm not sure why this is being voted to be moved to ServerFault, as this is a question specific to a standalone Outlook client(s). I don't have/want an exchange server or domain controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Microsoft article
[How to deploy a default email signature in Outlook](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2691977)
describes the procedure to follow.

1. Close Outlook.
2. Delete the First-Run value under the following key in the Windows registry:
   `KEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\x.0\Outlook\Setup`
   Note, x.0 depends on your version of Outlook.
   Outlook 2013 = 15.0
   Outlook 2010 = 14.0
   Outlook 2007 = 12.0
3. Add/deploy the signature files and folders you want to use for email signatures to the `\Signatures` folder under the user profile. This location varies, depending on your version of Windows.
   **Windows Vista,Windows 7, or Windows 8**
   `%userprofile%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Signatures`
   **Windows XP**
   `%userprofile%\Application Data\Microsoft\Signatures`
4. Create or locate the following key in the registry:
   `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\x.0\Common\MailSettings`
   or
   `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Office\x.0\Common\MailSettings`
   Note, x.0 depends on your version of Outlook.
5. Create the following value(s) under the MailSettings registry key:
   Name: **NewSignature**
   Type: REG_EXPAND_SZ
   Value: The name of signature to use for new messages (see step 3 above for signature names)
   Name: **ReplySignature**
   Type: REG_EXPAND_SZ
   Value: The name of signature to use for reply messages (see step 3 above for signature names)
6. Start Outlook and open a new e-mail message.
   The signature specified in the NewSignature registry value will automatically appear in the body of the message.

Comment: Awesome! Do you know if you can use variables in the signature itself, or must you make a hard copy of the signatures for each user?

Comment: The Outlook signature itself cannot contain variables, but there's no reason you couldn't write a login script that would create three signature files (.rtf, .htm, and .txt) that contain the information specific to each user. These might help : [article 1](http://jamiemckillop.wordpress.com/2012/07/06/deploying-a-standard-outlook-signature-52/) and [article 2](http://otori-braindump.blogspot.fr/2010/08/vbscript-deploy-outlook-stationery-and.html).